# How to add Flagsmith API authentication header

Tags: javascript, java, typescript, feature-flags, flagsmith

I am trying to consume the Flagsmith APIs as documented [here](https://api.flagsmith.com/api/v1/docs/) .

It seems some APIs like -- [/flags/](https://api.flagsmith.com/api/v1/flags/) need "x-environment-key" header, which is working.

But for others like [/environments/](https://api.flagsmith.com/api/v1/environments/) "x-environment-key" does not work. I have tried a bearer token authorisation by obtaining the API key ( Authorization: Bearer <> ). But that doesn't work either. There is no clear documentation on the authentication mechanism ( or I have missed it ).

Can someone throw some pointers ?

Answer (score 2):

x-environment-key is for the SDK endpoints, where as /environments is an admin endpoint used in the dashboard to list a project's environments.
Those endpoints are protected via an API token, so you'd need to send

`authorization: Token $API_TOKEN`

You can find your API token in your **account settings** under **keys**

[image]